# How would I solve this second order non-homogenous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> [$2.$ a$)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VNoq.png) Find the solution of the second order differential equation
> $$ \frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2} + 4\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + 5y = e^{-2x}\sin\left(bx\right), $$
> $\qquad\,$where $ b\neq 1$ and subject to the boundary conditions $y\left(0\right) = 0, y'\left(0\right)=0$.
> $\tag*{$[10\;\text{marks}]$}$

Hello everyone, I've been really struggling to solve this question so I would appreciate some help. I'm able to solve it up until the particular integral. At which point I get $y(x) = xe^{-2x} \cdot (A\cos bx + B\sin bx)$ what do I do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the DE as
$$(ye^{2x})''+ye^{2x}=\sin (bx)$$
$$w''+w=\sin (bx)$$
$$\implies w_h=C_1 \cos x + C_2 \sin x$$
Then try for $b\ne \pm 1$:
$$w_p=A \sin (bx)$$
As a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the homogeneous equation to recover the two fundamental solutions $y_1=e^{-2x} \cos(x)$ and $y_2=e^{-2x} \sin(x)$. Since $b\neq1$, we can use the ansatz (converting to complex exponentials makes things a bit cleaner)

$$y = e^{-2x}(A\sin(bx)+B\cos(bx)) = A' e^{(-2+ib)x} + B' e^{(-2-ib)x}$$

Substitute $y$ and its derivatives into the ODE and solve for $A',B'$ and hence $A,B$. You'll end up with

$$(1-b^2) A' e^{(-2+ib)x} + (1-b^2) B' e^{(-2-ib)x} = \frac{e^{(-2+ib)x}-e^{(-2-ib)x}}{2i}$$

$$\implies A' = \frac1{2i(1-b^2)}, B' = -\frac1{2i(1-b^2)}$$